# C# TcpClient ReadAsync reading a large message

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcpclient

I have a C# TcpClient to read data asynchronously. The simplified code is as below:

```
public async Task StartReading(CancellationToken token)
{
    // To fit the largest package
    const int BufferSize = 524288;

    while(true)
    {
         var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
         int bytesRead = await this.networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BufferSize);
                                          .WithWaitCancellation(token);            

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                 Console.Read(string.Fromat("{0} bytes received."));

                 // Run processing at background process
                 Task.Run(() => ProcessData(buffer, bytesRead));
            }
            else
            {
                // If received 0 bytes then a tcp connection is terminated
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

The recieved package may contain one or more messages started with STX and ending with ETX, no package length is sent. This feed is provide by 3rd party and won't be changed.
During testing it appeared that the server sends data in 8192 chunks so a message could be split into two subsequent chuncks and failed to be processed. 
Here is a log:
8192 bytes received
Messages 89 processed / 1 failed
8192 bytes received
Messages 89 processed / 2 failed
8192 bytes received
Messages 89 processed / 2 failed
2349 bytes received
Messages 34 processed / 1 failed

Sync Read doesn't help as well. How can I manage it?

Answer (score 6):

Fundamentally, TCP is a *stream-based* protocol. You're trying to treat it as a *packet-based* protocol. Don't do that.

The data provides its own delimiter - so use that. If a message isn't received completely, remember those bytes and then handle them when the rest of the message is received. (Bear in mind that it's possible that the message won't be completely received on the next read call either...)